# Android Firebase topic messaging not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that should listen to some Firebase messaging topics and also send messages to this topic.

Here is my code:

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFMService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //...
    }
}
public class MainActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test");
        //...
        Messaging mess = new Messaging(this.getApplication());
        mess.execute("asdf");
    }
}

public class Messaging extends AsyncTask {
Application app;

Messaging(Application app) {
    this.app = app;
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    try {
        String rawData = "{\"to\":\"/topics/test\"," +
                "\"data\": {" +
                "\"message\": \"Test message\"}}";
        String encodedData = URLEncoder.encode(rawData, "UTF-8");

        URL u = new URL("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + app.getString(R.string.api_key));
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        os.write(encodedData.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

This is in the manifest:

```
<service
    android:name=".MessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The sending works without throwing any exceptions, but I don't receive notifications (also not if i send a message from the firebase console.)

where have I gone wrong? Have I messed up the topic subscription or something else?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

I also have this class:

```
public class MyInstanceIdListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";
private static final String TOPIC = "test";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: " + token);

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance()
            .subscribeToTopic(TOPIC);
}
}
```

Comment: I think you are not showing your subclass of FirebaseMessagingService that retrieve the notification send from Firebase console. You can look at this link. It can be helpful to you. https://inducesmile.com/android/android-firebase-push-notification-with-topic-message-subscription/

Comment: Shouldn't the `MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService` be the  retriever?

Comment: Yes, because you will ovverride onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) method

Comment: the first 8 lines of the posted code are this specific class...

Comment: Ok, did you generate token required for device identification 
 using FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Comment: well, yes...
i have got it before the subscription to the topic; and there is a class that extends the FirebaseInstanceIdService and a Manifest entry.

I have updated the code...

Comment: So this line - Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom()); does not output any message when you send message from console?

Comment: no...
this is also a breakpoint, and when I debug it, no messages are received.

Comment: Can you test this <service
    android:name=".MessagingService"
    android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

Comment: Also check if your project package name is same in Firebase console.

Comment: I wouldn't know how....
(Sorry I have not done a lot with android yet.) but I got this from [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#9);

I already checked that...

Comment: In the same page your reference - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#3, you need to create Firebase project that you will enter the package name of your android project.

Comment: I did that. I meant I am not sure how to test the intent filter... Sorry